# Cython - error when trying to access contents of pointer to struct

Tags: python, c, pointers, struct, cython

I have a `cdef`ed class in Cython which looks very similar to this:

```
cdef class AprilTagDetector:
    cdef capriltag.apriltag_detector_t* _apriltag_detector

    def __cinit__(self):
        self._apriltag_detector = capriltag.apriltag_detector_create();
        # standard null checks
    # standard __dealloc__(self) here

    property quad_decimate:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._apriltag_detector.quad_decimate
```

The corresponding `.pxd` file looks like this:

```
cdef extern from "apriltag.h":
    # The detector itself
    ctypedef struct apriltag_detector_t:
        pass

    # Detector constructor and destructor
    apriltag_detector_t* apriltag_detector_create()
    void apriltag_detector_destroy(apriltag_detector_t* td);
```

The problem is, when I go to compile this code, it spits out this error:

```
property quad_decimate:
    def __get__(self):
        return self._apriltag_detector.quad_decimate             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

apriltags.pyx:47:14: Cannot convert 'apriltag_detector_t *' to Python object
```

What's going on here? I haven't been able to figure it out from the Cython docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, thankfully, figured out the problem when working on this project with a friend at a hackerspace.
The problem is in the `ctypedef struct apriltag_detector_t` block.
When I wrote `pass` in the block, I thought that Cython would automatically  work out the internal contents of the struct, and let me access the element(s) I needed - here, `quad_decimate`.

Not so.
To get Cython to understand the contents of a struct, you **will have to** tell it what's in the struct as so:

```
ctypedef struct apriltag_detector_t:
    float quad_decimate
```